# Having touble installing SWI-Prolog on Linux

Tags: installation, prolog, swi-prolog

I am following the installation instructions from SWI-Prolog's site. I am on a Linux machine.

First I git-clone the repo and cd into swipl-devel.

Next I run the commands:

```
git submodule update --init
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${install_under}/swipl" -G Ninja ..
ninja
```

This all goes smoothly.

Next, when I run `ctest -j 4` I get back:

```
98% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 66

Total Test time (real) =  15.23 sec

The following tests FAILED:
     24 - swipl:xsb/nonmt_tests (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

I then become root and run `ninja install`. Here is what I get back:

```
[12/13] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Set runtime path of "/home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build/install_under: command not found/swipl/lib/swipl/bin/x86_64-linux/swipl" to "/home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build/install_under: command not found/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux"
-- Set runtime path of "/home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build/install_under: command not found/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux/libswipl.so.8.3.6" to "/home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build/install_under: command not found/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux"
-- Set runtime path of "/home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build/install_under: command not found/swipl/lib/swipl/bin/x86_64-linux/swipl-ld" to "/home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build/install_under: command not found/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux"
CMake Error at src/cmake_install.cmake:509 (EXECUTE_PROCESS):
  EXECUTE_PROCESS given unknown argument "command".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:70 (include)                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                               
FAILED: CMakeFiles/install.util                                                                                                                                                                
cd /home/nick/prolog/swipl-devel/build && /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake                                                                                                                
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something really going wrong.

I have never had the `swipl:xsb/nonmt_tests` tests failing (whatever they are).

Is the shell variable `install_under` properly set when you run the above?

For example, I always install under a directory like `/usr/local/logic/swipl`, so here you would have to say

`-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/logic/swipl`

or

`export install_under=/usr/local/logic/`

in your case (not sure whether the export is needed, it sets an environment variable).

Comment: running `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/logic" -G Ninja ..`  did the trick.

Comment: My personal build script is hewre: [swiprologpull.sh](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/compiling)